# Can I use jdk 10.0.1 as my intelliJ's project sdk

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I'm having trouble because I'm about to train myself to know about kotlin and when I watched some tutorials their Project SDK or JDK Versions for their IntelliJ are like 1.7 or 1.8 but mine is 10.0.1 which is a very long jump from 1.7 or 1.8.

Comment: try using 10.0.1 and see if you haver any issues. Because it is java it must be backward compatible.

Comment: Yeah after I posted this question I tried to use it and I have no issues so far but I'm still at the basic but if something comes up or some issues then I will do some research about or update this question. thank you so much.